# Java - Netbeans: Opening form *as javax.swing.JPanel. Could not use the declared superclass: *

Tags: java, swing, exception, netbeans, jpanel

When i press on the "Design view" of my jPanel, i receive the error:

> Form loaded with errors:
>
> Error in loading component: [JPanel] -> (an instance) Cannot create
>   instance of (class name) the component cannot be loaded
>
> Failed to initialize layout of this container.

When i read the logfile, it says:
 Opening form *as javax.swing.JPanel. Could not use the declared superclass: *

Can somebody help me in this matter?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Even Once or twice I got similar issue, then I found there is a bug [Click here](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=150536)

Comment: fallow the link in my above comment